# Facebook graph api request ,,, get my info beside my friends info

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

You know guys that this request return my friends info :

```
requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
```

But can I also get my info too using the above request or I should send another one like this:

```
requestWithGraphPath:@"me"
```